# What DAPPS Can Be Built On EUTXO Chains That Account Based Chains Cannot Make?

Tags: utxo, decentralized-applications, eutxo, ethereum, dapp-bridge

I remember reading that the EUTXO model is a superset of the account-based model. My question is does this mean that there are some types of Dapps that can only be built on EUTXO chains, and if so what are they?